# How to adjust visual components that don't scale correctly in a high DPI aware Windows application made in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.4-sydney, highdpi

In a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58773669/how-to-correctly-design-a-delphi-application-ui-that-is-high-dpi-aware-4k-ready) I managed to adjust the "padding" between components using `Monitor.PixelsPerInch`.

Now I have a different problem: I have a "..." (browse) `TButton` at the left of a `TEdit` (path). At design time both VCL components have the same height in their `Height` property **and** visually. At runtime under a 4K monitor (scaling of 120%) the components are scaled differently and the `TButton` have like 3 pixels more at the bottom vs the `TEdit` which gives an inconsistent GUI.

How can I adjust the height after the automatic (magic) scaling happened? I'm still using Delphi 10.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Button1.Height:=Edit1.Height;
Button1.Top:=Edit1.Top;
```

in either FormCreate, FormActivate or FormResize.

(provided they are both children of the same parent)

Comment: Wow, I feel dumb to not have tried this before posting my question :P At design time Button1.Height = Edit1.Height and Button1.Top = Edit1.Top (they have the same parent) but not at runtime after the rescale (if under high DPI). I wonder why? VCL bug??

Comment: @AlexV: It depends on your definition of "Bug". There are various ways to scale a component. A TEditBox is perhaps scaled using the Font and then the size of surrounding box follows, whereas the TButton may be scaled based on its current size, and then the font is adjusted to match. That (or some other difference) may lead to a small discrepancy. It's not an exact science :-).

Comment: Yeah I guess you are right :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `TRelativePanel` as a container of both `TEdit` and `TButton`.
Set `TButton` properties `AlignTopWith`, `AlignBottomWith`, `RightOf` to the `TEdit` instance. Also set `AlignWithMargins` to `True` and adjust the `Margins`

Answer (score 0):

Asuming we are talking about a VCL application: A form has an event [OnBeforeMonitorDpiChanged](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/Vcl.Forms.TCustomForm.OnBeforeMonitorDpiChanged) and [OnAfterMonitorDpiChanged](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/Vcl.Forms.TCustomForm.OnAfterMonitorDpiChanged). In this event you can adjust whatever you like.

Alternatively you can override the form's message handler for [WM_DPICHANGED](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/wm-dpichanged):

procedure WMDpiChanged(var _Msg: TWMDpi); message WM_DPICHANGED;